# Excel: Delete all rows not containing data in certain columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to delete certain rows in an **Excel** spreadsheet. The criteria is something as follows:

I want to keep all rows that have data in columns `C`, `E` and `G` for example, and delete all other rows not containing data in either.

So if a row has data in `E` and `G`, but not in `C`, it must be deleted for example.

Comment: Try this: CTRL A (select all) tools->sort columns C,E, and G.  Click Ok.  Blanks get shifted to the top, so just delete the top ### rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column with this formula:

`=OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(E2),ISBLANK(G2))`

It will result in `True` or `False`
If any of the cells C2, E2 or G2 is Blank (empty) the formula will result `True`
Sort all the Data you have including the new column (True, False)
Sort by this column descending (True will be at the top False at the end)
and now you can delete the top rows